# visual studio express 2012 for winjs project

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I developed a small game using html5/javascript.
I hope to run it on windows phone.
I am using visual studio express 2012 to develop app.
As I know, windows phone 8.0 supports winjs/html5 development.

But I can not find where is javascript project creator(likes in VS 2012 for winrt) in visual studio express 2012.

There is only html5 app option under c# item

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Express 2012 can be used to write Windows 8 apps with WinJS, but not Windows Phone 8 apps. Writing apps with HTML/CSS/JS and WinJS on is supported starting with Windows Phone 8.1, in which case you need Visual Studio Express **2013**. See http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs.